# Secure ASP.NET MVC controller method from random posts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller method for an ajax request that I'm curious as to how I can stop random folks from submitting data to that url. I want to make sure it's coming from that specific form.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DemographicsSave(FormCollection collection)
{   
    return Json("Patient Saved", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a NuGet package created by my friend for just this very purpose and shores up some security "holes" by default. It should save you some time in implementation!

http://nuget.org/packages/ValidationAndAuthenticationByDefault.MVC3

Alternatively you can add to your controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

Followed by the following in your view:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: Worth Noting that the token needs to be in a form in the view.